# Access S3 (S3://bucketname/folder) via Google Cloud VM privately via VPN or Partner Interconnect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, vpn

Is it possible to connect to S3 folder(S3://bucket/folder) from a Google VM over a VPN tunnel or via Partner Interconnect?

Comment: The API endpoints for Amazon S3 are on the Internet. So, any method that gives access to the Internet will let you access S3.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein , I am looking for a way to access via S3://format and not https://s3-private-endpoint format.

Comment: You can use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to access Amazon S3 using that format. However, you will need to provide AWS credentials and have a connection to the Internet.

Comment: thanks @JohnRotenstein. Unfortunately don't have the Internet connection but have the tunnel setup.